# Getting ios build error for flutter project after using library flutter_sharing_intent

Tags: ios, flutter

Trying to build a flutter project where i am using a library **flutter_sharing_intent**.
Done all the configuration based on instruction.
Using most latest stable flutter build.
Unable to understand below error and how to fix this.

Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from 'build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Share Extension.appex' to 'build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/Share Extension.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output 'build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from 'build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Share Extension.appex' to 'build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/Share Extension.appex'

Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node:  ->

command:  ->

node: Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfrdacvowsvbmeaeowuwndtcoaof/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ExtractedAppShortcutsMetadata.stringsdata ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Release:ExtractAppIntentsMetadata ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase6-copy-files ->

node: <Copy build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/Share Extension.appex> ->

CYCLE POINT ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Release:Copy build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/Share Extension.appex build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Share Extension.appex ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5--cp--embed-pods-frameworks ->

node: Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfrdacvowsvbmeaeowuwndtcoaof/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-E7D4684E40C2338C9BC4AD43-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-input-files-58b18613296193edb74fc3e59610c0d3-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Release:WriteAuxiliaryFile Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfrdacvowsvbmeaeowuwndtcoaof/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-E7D4684E40C2338C9BC4AD43-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-input-files-58b18613296193edb74fc3e59610c0d3-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase4-thin-binary ->

node:  ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Release:PhaseScriptExecution Thin Binary Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfrdacvowsvbmeaeowuwndtcoaof/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh ->

node: build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: [ ->

directoryContents: build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

node: build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Release:ProcessInfoPlistFile build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist ios/Runner/Info.plist ->

node: build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/Share Extension.appex ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Release:Copy build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/Share Extension.appex build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Share Extension.appex

Encountered error while building for device.